# Associated models and exceptions

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have model **Schedule** which associated with another model **Chamber**. 
And i'm getting the problem when associated model data is null. 
It's normal behavior, cause it's not required field.

**Upgrade**: **Schedule** model is a part of scheduleTree model, which used by store loading data from server.

```
Ext.define('...SchedulesTree', {
    extend : '...TreeStore',
    model: "...ScheduleTree",
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        text: "root",
        children: [],
        loaded: true
    },
    paramsAsHash : true,
    proxy : {
        type: "direct",
        autoLoad: false,
        api : {
            read: registratorAction.getScheduleNode
        },
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            root : "records",
            totalProperty: 'total'
       }
    }
});

Ext.define("...ScheduleTree", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",


...
    associations: [   
        {
            type: "hasMany",
            model: "Unimed.model.staff.Schedule",
            name: "schedules",
            getterName: "schedules"
        }
    ]
});


Ext.define("...Schedule", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
fields: [
    {name: "timeBegin", type: "date", dateFormat: "time"},
    {name: "timeEnd", type: "date", dateFormat: "time"}
],
proxy: {
    type: "direct",
    reader: {
        type: "json"
    }
},
associations: [
    {
        type: "belongsTo",      
        model: "..LpuPosition", 
        associationKey: "lpuPosition",
        getterName: "lpuPosition",
        associatedName: "lpuPosition"
    },
    {
        type: "belongsTo",
        model: "...Chamber",
        associationKey: "chamber",
        getterName: "chamber",
        associatedName: "chamber"
    }
]
});
```

When i'm getting chamber:

```
chamber = schedule.chamber();
```

and there is no linked data i'm getting exception: 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'.

I can make workaround by looking raw data, but may be there exists more elegance solution?

Comment: Any possibility you can link the JSON received from your server?

Comment: Excuse me, but i did not understand

Comment: Well your store needs to look for data somewhere, you have a direct proxy, your server should return some sort of data to your store. Formatted in JSON. Could you post the returned data of your server?
Are you also sure your schedule object contains any form of data?

Comment: As Johan suggested, you have defined a `direct` proxy but did not provide `directFn` or `api` to tell the proxy what server scripts to use to retrieve json data from the server. Hence the 'undefined is not a function'. There question you should answer is: where does the model get the data from?

Comment: I've understand. Question was updated